# How to delete bicep template and the resources it has deployed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-bicep

How can I delete or update bicep template and all the resources it has deployed? just like we can delete or update cloudformation and terraform template

az deployment commands don't have update option and while using az deployment delete it does not delete the resources

Answer (score 10):

It has. You need to use `Complete` mode

```
az deployment group create -f ./main.bicep -g my-rg --mode Complete
```

As it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#complete-mode)

> In complete mode, Resource Manager deletes resources that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template.

Comment: Hey @Krzysztof Madej, thanks for your reply. I am writing Azure Policy which are scoped to subscription and management level. In that case I don't have any resource group where I deploy Azure policies. Do you know how to update or delete resources then ?

Comment: No, it works only with deployments to resource group. I don't know a way how to achieve on deployments on Managemnt Groupe scope.

Comment: Thankyou for responding back.

Comment: This won't delete the resources deployed by the bicep template (as the OP asked). Instead, it will delete resources that are *not* in the template. You could remove the resources from the template and then run it again, but it would then still delete any resources that were never in the template... This is not the equivalent of Terraform.

Comment: This only delete the resource. The existing configuration or sub-resource won't be deleted, eg a Cosmos Container, Blob Container ...

Comment: This is not what was asked hence cannot be deemed as a valid answer.

Answer (score -1):

Create an empty bicep file and deploy it in complete mode.

```bash
# Create an empty bicep file
echo '' > empty.bicep
# Deploy it into the resource group in 'complete' mode
az deployment group create --template-file empty.bicep --resource-group 'my-rg' --mode complete
# Clean up
rm empty.bicep
```

Comment: This is also a wrong answer since this will delete ALL the resources in the group even the ones that were not deployed using the Bicep template.